# Storing list from nested loop into a matrix in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops, montecarlo

I'm trying to compute the estimation errors for a monte-carlo integration of the integral below for a number of different sample sizes.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
N = 20
sample_size = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
truetheta = 0.4

# for loop creates sample size 2, 4, 8, 16 ....1024...
for n in range(N):
    sample_size[n] = 2**(n+1)

# for loop which computes estimation errors for different sample sizes
naive_error = []
for i in (sample_size):
     x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, i)
     y = 2*(2*x -1)**4
     naive_error.append(abs(np.sum((y)/i)-truetheta))
```

Now, this code yields a list of 20 estimation errors, one for each sample size.  However, I also want to to produce a matrix with M values for each sample size. This seems like a very simple operation but I am new to python and I'm struggling hard with the syntax. I was thinking of putting my first loop into another loop from 1 to M. But I'm not sure how to  store an entire list from a loop into a Matrix or how to properly setup the nested loop. Suggestions for solutions to my problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: When I started using Numpy, I worked through this whole tutorial and it really helped me: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html After doing it, I think you'll know how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, that was a great resource. I managed to solve my problem.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the matrix:

```
N = 20
sample_size = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
truetheta = 0.4

# for loop creates sample size 2, 4, 8, 16 ....1024...
for n in range(N):
    sample_size[n] = 2**(n+1)

M = 10
CRUDE_ERROR = np.zeros((M, N))  ##matrix to store errors in
for j in range(0, M):
    naive_error = []            ##list to store errors in
    for i in (sample_size):
        x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, i)
        y = 2*(2*x -1)**4
        naive_error.append(abs(np.sum((y)/i)-truetheta)**2)
    CRUDE_ERROR[ j] = naive_error
```